# Socket callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket, socket.io

Estoy practicando Sockets en JavaScript, este es el codigo del la parte del front-end

```
var socket = io();
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (!params.has('nombre')) {
    window.location = 'index.html';
    throw new Error('El nombre y sala son necesarios');
}
var usuario = {
    nombre: params.get('nombre')
};
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Conectado al servidor');

    socket.emit('entrarChat', usuario, function(resp) {
        console.log('Usuarios conectados',resp);
    });
});
```

Este es el código de parte del back-end

```
const { io } = require('../server');
const {Usuarios} = require('../classes/usuarios');
const usuarios = new Usuarios(); 

io.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.on('entrarChat', (data, callback) => {
        if (!data.nombre) {
            return callback({
                error: true,
                mensaje: 'El nombre/sala es necesario'
            });
        }
        let personas = usuarios.agregarPersona(client.id,data.nombre);
        //ERROR            
        callback(personas);    
    });    
});
```

Al momento de ejecutar me aparece que **callback is not a function**

Comment: donde defines tu callback??

Comment: No es socket.emit('entrarChat', usuario, function(resp)??, el callback lo paso como parametro, o asi no funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la verdad no se cual era el error en concreto pero de igual comento el código final que no tiene ningún error.
Front-end

```
var socket = io();
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (!params.has('nombre')) {
    window.location = 'index.html';
    throw new Error('El nombre y sala son necesarios');
}
var usuario = {
    nombre: params.get('nombre')
};
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Conectado al servidor');

    socket.emit('entrarChat', usuario, function(resp) {
        console.log('Usuarios conectados',resp);
    });
});
```

Back-end

```
const { io } = require('../server');
const {Usuarios} = require('../classes/usuarios');
const usuarios = new Usuarios(); 

io.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.on('entrarChat', (data, callback )=> {
        if (!data.nombre) {
            return callback({
                error: true,
                mensaje: 'El nombre/sala es necesario'
            });
        }
        let personas = usuarios.agregarPersona(client.id,data.nombre);
        callback(personas);    
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema ya que estoy siguiendo el mismo tutorial de udemy, y la solucion es dejar solo una ventana de la aplicacion abierta y reinicia nodemon.
[image: solo una pestaña de localhost:3000]